Angular - Lazy Loading Same Module with Two Routes
I have this routing currently in my app-routing module:

{
    path: 'school',
    component: SchoolComponent
  },
{
    path: 'student',
    component: StudentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'student/view',
    component: StudentDetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'student/view/:id',
    component: StudentDetailsComponent
  }

Now I am trying to do lazy loading to a StudentModule with a student-routing module for the 3 paths: student, student/view and student/view:id.
How I can do this to the app-routing module and student-routing module?
Here the last two paths are mapped to same component.
I am new to angular and could not find a proper example.

Lazy loading means loading the feature right when it's about to be used : once loaded you can use it as much as you want after that. You don't need to lazy load something twice. Or maybe I didn't get your question correctly ?

Assuming we have a student module created, we can add children routes to simplify the /student/view and /student/view:param routes so that we do not have to define /student twice. The outer path will be '' so that this is the default route when the module is loaded.
student-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentComponent } from './student.component';
import { StudentDetailsComponent } from '../student-details/student-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StudentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'view',
        component: StudentDetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'view/:id',
        component: StudentDetailsComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class StudentRoutingModule {}

To then lazy load the student module from your app module, you can import it as so: (please note this is where we define the root path for the module student)
app.routes.ts:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'student',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./student/student.module').then((m) => m.StudentModule),
  },
];

The routing will work in your browser as:

yourdomain/student/view  -> student details component
yourdomain/student/view/1234 -> student details component
yourdomain/student -> student component


If you want to display all the students you can use:
{
    path: 'students',
    component: StudentsComponent
}

If you want to display students details by id then use:
{
    path: 'student/view/:id',
    component: StudentDetailsComponent
}

StudentsComponent will contain list of all the students with a button to navigate to StudentDetailsComponent by id.
